# dunst - i3 - origin option is ignored

Tags: 22.04, notification

Dunst ignores the `origin = bottom-left` option in *~/.config/dunst/dunstrc*.
It keeps showing notifications in the top-right corner of the monitor.
Geometry section of my *dunstrc* is the following:

```
### Geometry ###
geometry = "300x5-30+20"

# Position the notification in the top right corner
origin = bottom-left

# Offset from the origin
offset = 10x50

# Scale factor. It is auto-detected if value is 0.
scale = 0

# Maximum number of notification (0 means no limit)
notification_limit = 0
```

I'm working with Ubuntu 22.04.3.

EDIT:
I noticed that the `origin` option is missing in `man dunst`, is there a way to achieve the same behavior in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I've found that the latest `dunst` version available through `apt` is the 1.5.0 (2020-07-23) which does not provide the `origin` option.
The solution that worked for me was to download and compile the code directly from the [dunst GitHub repository](https://github.com/dunst-project/dunst).